# SAPUI5: How can I filter my list between two views?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5, url-routing

I have two XML views and I can navigate between them using routing. In the first view I have a list with weekdays, in the second view I want to show the meals related to a weekday (linked with an ID). Now I only can show the whole list with meals (unfiltered). The data comes from `diet.json`.

[Here is my code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ldvvmjkyYFb3BFcDc2d2xmRDA/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a routing parameter (the weekday or that id you mentioned) to pass the filter option.
(Look at https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef.html)
 and than pass create a filter:
(Look at:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/5295470d7eee46c1898ee46c1b9ad763.html)

I would suggest you pass the name of the weekday as a routing parameter, because it looks nicer to the user.

That also gives you the advantage that you can bookmark your selection in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

//**DETAIL.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/demo/nav/controller/BaseController"
], function (BaseController) {
    "use strict";
    return BaseController.extend("sap.ui.demo.nav.controller.DETAIL", {
        onInit: function () {
            var oRouter = this.getRouter();
            oRouter.getRoute("meal").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);

        },
        _onRouteMatched : function (oEvent) {
            var oArgs, oView;
            oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");

            oView = this.getView();
            var context = new sap.ui.model.Context(oView.getModel(), "/" + oArgs.dayId);
            oView.setBindingContext(context);
            var oItemTemplate =new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                    title:"{items}"
                });
            var oList  = oView.getContent()[0].getContent()[0];
            var oBindingInfo = {
                path:"/meals",
                template: oItemTemplate,
                filters:[
                    new sap.ui.model.Filter("dayId", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oArgs.dayId)
                    ]
            };
            oList.bindAggregation("items",oBindingInfo);                     

        }
    });
});
```

**//DETAIL.view.xml**

```
<mvc:View
  controllerName="sap.ui.demo.nav.controller.DETAIL"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <Page id="mealPage" title="{i18n>Detail}"
    showNavButton="true"
    navButtonPress="onNavBack"
    class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
    <content>
       <List id="mealListID" headerText="Meals" noDataText="Not Found">
    </List>
    </content>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```